# Winforms Error 'InvalidOperationException' while starting the app

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# VS2012 windows application made on Windows 7. When I sent the exe files to client, they are getting this error when running the exe. Getting the following error:

```
Problem signature:

Problem Event Name: CLR20r3

Problem Signature 01: AB.exe

Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0

Problem Signature 03: 5954cd46

Problem Signature 04: System.Core

Problem Signature 05: 4.6.1087.0

Problem Signature 06: 583e5c3a

Problem Signature 07: 73e

Problem Signature 08: 65

Problem Signature 09: System.InvalidOperationException

OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7

Locale ID: 1033
Additional Information 1: 2f1f
Additional Information 2: 2f1f756aa68c8e23d7adf9827d731b5b
Additional Information 3: 80cb
Additional Information 4: 80cb6630dd7c18e04a18b500b9c39bb0

Read our privacy statement online:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Have you tried sending them the debug version instead of release? Because this error isnt that helpful as to specifics

Comment: Most common reason for `InvalidOperationException` would be your code is accessing a UI object from a thread other than the UI thread. But, really it could be just about anything. There's not anything the Stack Overflow community can do with so little information.

Comment: Which version of the .NET Framework is used by the app an which version is installed on the clients that are using the app?

Comment: Thank you guys for the inputs. I have sent them the debug folder and the framework I have used is 4.5. I wasn't sure as that else to ask to my client but now I can ask more details on this error.

Comment: create a try catch statement in the main load of the app or form and output the message to a messagebox.That way you will get more information on the invalidoperation causing the exception. if you are lucky you will get a clue. And could isolate whether its the clients .net version or your code that's really causing the trouble.